# Python File readline() method skipping specific lines of my source file?

Tags: python

For an image classification project I am working on I generated a report as a text file. For each training-validation run, the app writes to the report file a title, several lines each one summarizing one layers of the model used and finally a result line that tells what were the accuracy, loss and how many epochs it took. Here is a description of the report file:

```
>>>test 1<<<
input   convolution channels: 8 activation: relu    l1 regularization: 0.0
hidden  maxpool pool size: 2
hidden  convolution channels: 64    activation: relu    l1 regularization: 0.0
hidden  maxpool pool size: 2
hidden  convolution channels: 64    activation: relu    l1 regularization: 0.0
hidden  flatten 
hidden  dense   neurons: 64 activation: relu    l1 regularization: 0.0
output  dense   neurons: 10 activation: softmax l1 regularization: 0.0
Best validation at epoch 10 with loss 0.65450 and  accuracy 0.96423

>>>test 2<<<
input   convolution channels: 16    activation: relu    l1 regularization: 0.0
hidden  maxpool pool size: 2
hidden  convolution channels: 64    activation: relu    l1 regularization: 0.0
hidden  maxpool pool size: 2
hidden  convolution channels: 64    activation: relu    l1 regularization: 0.0
hidden  flatten 
hidden  dense   neurons: 64 activation: relu    l1 regularization: 0.0
output  dense   neurons: 10 activation: softmax l1 regularization: 0.0
Best validation at epoch 12 with loss 0.47489 and  accuracy 0.97593
```

Now I need to go through that report file and find the test model that gave me the best results so I made a function that uses *readline()* to navigate to the line with the info I seek (**"Best validation at [...]"** in the prior report description). I was hoping recovering that line and using a *str.split()* on it would allow me to get the data embedded in these result lines but the run crashed because the line I got to wasn't the one I was looking for but the one after it. Seeing no reason why I would skip that line in my code, I tried just printing a 22 lines of *readline().split()* and see what I would get (22 because that's enough lines for the first 2 reports statements in the file). Here is the debug code I ran:

```
ioData = open(REPORT_FILE, 'r')
for i in range(22):
   print("{}".format(ioData.readline().split()))
ioData.close()
```

And the output I got from it:

```
['>>>test', '1<<<']
['input', 'convolution', 'channels:', '8', 'activation:', 'relu', 'l1', 'regularization:', '0.0']
['hidden', 'maxpool', 'pool', 'size:', '2']
['hidden', 'convolution', 'channels:', '64', 'activation:', 'relu', 'l1', 'regularization:', '0.0']
['hidden', 'maxpool', 'pool', 'size:', '2']
['hidden', 'convolution', 'channels:', '64', 'activation:', 'relu', 'l1', 'regularization:', '0.0']
['hidden', 'flatten']
['hidden', 'dense', 'neurons:', '64', 'activation:', 'relu', 'l1', 'regularization:', '0.0']
['output', 'dense', 'neurons:', '10', 'activation:', 'softmax', 'l1', 'regularization:', '0.0']
[]
['>>>test', '2<<<']
['input', 'convolution', 'channels:', '16', 'activation:', 'relu', 'l1', 'regularization:', '0.0']
['hidden', 'maxpool', 'pool', 'size:', '2']
['hidden', 'convolution', 'channels:', '64', 'activation:', 'relu', 'l1', 'regularization:', '0.0']
['hidden', 'maxpool', 'pool', 'size:', '2']
['hidden', 'convolution', 'channels:', '64', 'activation:', 'relu', 'l1', 'regularization:', '0.0']
['hidden', 'flatten']
['hidden', 'dense', 'neurons:', '64', 'activation:', 'relu', 'l1', 'regularization:', '0.0']
['output', 'dense', 'neurons:', '10', 'activation:', 'softmax', 'l1', 'regularization:', '0.0']
[]
['>>>test', '3<<<']
['input', 'convolution', 'channels:', '32', 'activation:', 'relu', 'l1', 'regularization:', '0.0']
```

As you can see the printout shows each line split in word lists in the right order, but it skips the result line (last line of each report statement). As a result, instead of getting only two report statements in 22 lines, I got up to the two first lines of the third report statement.

I don't see any bug that would explain why that specific line gets skipped each time. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I ran your test above and got the expected output, including the line starting with "Best validation ..."

Comment: @Jerry thanks for the feedback. It makes me wonder if the problem comes from my file encoding maybe because I just ran it again and still get everything except for these lines...

Answer (score 0):

Oh I just figured it out. I had a duplicate file with the same name (must have generated it while debugging the report module) and that file is exactly the same as my report with the difference of the test results lines missing in it. This whole time I was indexing that file instead of the file with the results.

Sorry for wasting your time.